# Has the latest Codenameone build version lost functionality to scroll through container of rows containing URLImages?

Tags: codenameone

My CN1 based app has been on the App Store and Google Play for a couple of months and works fine but when I rebuild the identical code now on NetBeans locally or through CN1 Build Servers, I'm unable to scroll through the list of containers like before.

The code is similar to the CN1 contacts demo [here](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-mysql-demo).

From the .codenameone folder I see.....

```
UpdateStatus.properties
#
#Fri Mar 27 12:34:19 MDT 2020
CodenameOne_SRCzip=118
CodenameOneJar=118
CodeNameOneBuildClientJar=105
designer=108
CLDC11Jar=108
JavaSEJar=118
lastUpdate=1585334059359
guiBuilder=107
```

Thx @Shai for the suggestions.  A few updates:

1. Problem still occurred with setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true)
2. Tested the CN1 contacts list demo and scrolling worked
3. Primary difference with my code from that demo is that I’m using
   URLImage as in the 2nd CN1 example at
   https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/URLImage.html
4. I was able to get my container of rows to scroll again by removing
   any use of URLImage
5. Tested further by adding a URLImage to certain rows and not to others
   As soon as a row is assigned a URLImage it ceases to be a scrollable
   contact point for the container.  As long as some of the other rows
   don’t have URLImages the whole container can be scrolled (when my
   finger gets to one of those rows).  As soon as I run a trial where
   all the visible rows are URLImages, it’s not possible to scroll the
   container at all.
6. I tried to replicate this problem with the CN1 URLImage example
   ref’d above but that example links to a nestoria api that seems to
   be unavailable now.
7. Since this still works on code compiled in Jan. but fails for that
   same code recompiled now, I still wonder whether something has
   changed with my build process but I’ve not been able to replicate
   the issue with a CN1 demo.
8. Will keep this open for now in case there are further suggestions
   but I can get by for now by minimizing my use of URLImage (reluctant
   to call these URLImages earlier in the app session because a lot of
   times the user might not even need these icons).

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Can you modify the contacts demo to reproduce this issue so you can file an issue with sample code?
I don't see how URLImage should impact scrolling behsvior but it might break a layout if you have things such as nested scrollables etc.

Comment: Thx @Shai for the suggestion.  I spent several hours trying to add URLImages to the contacts demo but have probably passed the point of diminishing returns on that approach.  I kept running into other coding problems (c.getId() is alway null so the section where I added the URLImage code is always bypassed and I don’t see another method available to extract a contact from the sakila customer table).  

Perhaps a simpler way forward - the referenced URLImage demo in CN1’s documentation includes an out-of-date API, do you have a working version of that demo?  Thx, Mike

Comment: I'm not sure the API is out of date. If something is out of date we deprecate it. My concern is that you might have run into an unintended edge case that might indicate a bug either in our code or yours.

Comment: The link to http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api yields 404 Not Found.  Is there an alternative link to use for that 2nd CN1 URLImage example?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It seems the whole website is no longer available. Might be a temporary thing though.

Comment: Found that the nestoria api is rarely working and others have the same problem, see https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/nestoria-api-not-working-for-the-react-native-app-example/103435.  Since a) URLImage with InfiniteScrollAdapter was working for me but stopped with only changes to CN1 build version and b) CN1’s demo for this same situation also doesn’t work, the evidence is pointing toward a recent problem with CN1 builds.    Do you have a working example of URLImage with InfiniteScrollAdapter so that we can pinpoint the source of this problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, which demo doesn't work? The nestoria one? If there's a test case we can use to reproduce this please file an issue so we can evaluate it properly. Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd CN1 URLImage demo (See #3 in my question) doesn't work because it relies on an unavailable Nestoria API.  If you have a working URLImage/InfiniteScrollAdapter demo we could use that to file an issue and pinpoint the problem.   I see others (MobilitySol Uruguay) on the CN1 Discussion Forum have reported similar problems.

Comment: I'll try to convert the CN1 URLImage/InfiniteScrollAdapter demo to reference google icons instead of nestoria and see if that works.

Comment: OK but you didn't test it without the nestoria API right? If that happens with the Google images please file an issue with that test case. Thanks!

Comment: Figured out how to add URLImages to the CN1 Contacts Demo and the scrolling with URLImages still works.  Next will start making that code more like mine and see at what point the problem appears.  And will report back...

Comment: I thought the problem was the URLImages but it’s actually the lead component action listener that was getting added only to rows that also have URLImages.  Have opened an issue at https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3079

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. There was a major bug fix in that area that already caused a regression. I've assigned this to the current milestone and hope we can address this soon.

Answer (score 1):

No it didn't. Try the contacts demo, it's working right? How is your code different from that.

I'm guessing you're seeing artifacts related to the optimization of `setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint()`. To test this in your root form invoke:

```
form.setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true);
```

Before showing it. Then see if the problem is resolved. Assuming it is try to find the area that triggers this and follow up with us based on that. Notice that setting this to true has significant scrolling performance implications.